# Solving differential equations using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I need to solve this differential equation by power series:
$$y''+3xy'+(2x^{2}+6)y=0$$

Any help is great! Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is expected that you provide your own ideas and approaches to the solution, so that the answers may be directed to your real problems. Please add your first steps and indicate where you run into problems by editing your question.

Comment: I don't have first steps, I don't know how to begin, this is all new to me, I know its kind of wrong asking for help without investigate more by myself, but I'm kinda desperate here because of lack of time.

Comment: Start plugging in $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and calculate, this gives you a recurrence for $a_n$.

Comment: Look at the sidebar under "*Related*", there you will find examples that will show you the general approach. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/342721/115115 looks nice. Were there no examples done in your lessons?

Comment: I take online lessons, the material provided by the course is very simple, the exercises are complex. I usually investigate, but this time I had difficulties. Thanks.

Comment: So follow the hint by TooOldForMath and form the formal derivatives term-by-term, plug them into your differential equation, collect the powers of $x$ and group them by equal powers. Up to here is the easy part. Finding a solution for the resulting recurrence of the coefficients can be difficult or impossible. But in homework, the tasks are expected to be solvable.

Comment: Start simple plugging for example $y=\sum_{n=0}^4 a_n x^n$; compute the first and second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. Write your equation. Arrange terms for same powers of $x$. Since you want the expression be equal to $0$, you must cancel all terms. When this process will be understood, start with the infinite sum. By the way, do not forget that this is a second order ODE; so two arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$, and start performing all of the required operations. For example,
$$
 x^{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n}
$$
Write out all of the sums so that they have $x^{n}$ terms by using the kind of re-index trick shown above. Then use the fact that a power series is identically 0 iff all of the coefficients are identically 0. There will be some exceptional terms such as the coefficients of $x^{0}, x^{1}$, and then a general term that works for all other $n$. Expect low order terms to leave some constant(s) arbitrary--this is to be expected for non-singular, linear, second-order equations where the solutions have the form $ay_{1}+by_{2}$.